# Get index of one array item with RegExp

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I have array like

`var arr = ['8888', '2222|1', '6666', '4444|2']`

and I need get index of item which include first number (before `|`if symbol exists). Below is helpful RegExp, you can use it, works.

```
var result = new RegExp('\\b' + value.replace(/^(.*)\|.*$/, '$1') + '\\b').test(arr);

value = '2222'; \\true
value = '222'; \\false
value = '2222|1'; \\false
```

but I need index, not if item exists.

```
value = '8888'; \\0
value = '2222'; \\1
value = '222'; \\-1
value = '2222|1'; \\-1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

```js
var arr = ['8888', '2222|1', '6666', '4444|2']

const getIndex = (arr, n) => arr.findIndex(a => a.split("|")[0] === n);

console.log(getIndex(arr, "8888"))
console.log(getIndex(arr, "2222"))
console.log(getIndex(arr, "222"))
console.log(getIndex(arr, "2222|1"))
```

If `findIndex` is not supported, you could add [this polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex#Polyfill) to make 
 the method available in `Array.prototype`. You could also use a simple `for` loop and return when a match is found:

```js
var arr = ['8888', '2222|1', '6666', '4444|2']

function getIndex(arr, n) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].split("|")[0] === n)
      return i;
  }
  
  return -1;
}

console.log(getIndex(arr, "8888"))
console.log(getIndex(arr, "2222"))
console.log(getIndex(arr, "222"))
console.log(getIndex(arr, "2222|1"))
```

Another option suggested by T.J. Crowder:

```
var index = -1;
arr.some(function(a, i) {
  if (a.split("|")[0] === n) {
    index = i;
    return true;
  }
});
```

Comment: Okay, *now* it answers the question.

Comment: Looks what I need, but older IE has problem with findIndex(), maybe some ES5 solution?

Comment: @alexso You could add the [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex#Polyfill) to one of your js files. Otherwise you'd have to use a `for` loop

Comment: @alexso - If you don't want to use a polyfill, you can do `var index = -1; arr.some(function(a, i) { if (a.split("|")[0] === n) { index = i; return true; });` `some` is ES5.

Comment: @adiga and T.J. Crowder, thank you,.. btw how mention user with dots, whitespaces,.. and other special chars?

Comment: @alexso when you write, `@t` you get suggested the name and you can select it. You can only mention on handle in comment. Since you already @ me, T.J's name  won' show up in autofilll

Comment: ***On side note:-*** instead of splitting value of array on every call, we can simply use a curried function,